# calling SignalR hub from WebAPI controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5, Signal R 2.0.1, and WebAPI 2, and have a simple hub set up named ExportHub

```
public class ExportHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to call this from WebAPI so the UI can be updated.

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ExportHub>();
```

But within hubContext I don't see any reference to Send or addNewMessageToPage. How do I gain access to the methods within the hub?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to call any methods of specified hub. GetHubContext only returns a IHubContext of specified T Hub. Instead of calling Hub methods you should directly invoke method from your web api method to client like

```
Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your `Send` method static, and then call `hubContext.Send(string, string)`

Comment: If you make it static, then surely you won't have access to `Clients`?